# how to set route config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

hi i have a flight booking website i set route

```
routes.MapRoute(
"RouteFlights",
"{action}/{path}/{date}/{clock}/{count}",
new { controller = "Flight", 
action = "flights",
path = UrlParameter.Optional, 
date = UrlParameter.Optional, 
clock = UrlParameter.Optional, 
count = UrlParameter.Optional }
,new[] { "parvaz24pro.Controllers" }
);
```

and

```
[Route("flights/{path}/{date}/{clock}/{count}")]
public ActionResult flights(string path, string date...
```

it worked  only for urls like
 "www.site.com/flights/source-dest/2016-2-16/1/1"
 but not worked for  "www.site.com/flights/source-dest/2016-2-16"
 full route config link 
 http://preschool-doosti.com/RouteConfig.zip
 i can not find a solution

Comment: It seems like you are mixing two different things here. MvcAttributerouting and custom routes. Try making your parameters nullable({path?}/{date?}/{clock?}/{count?}) and apply only attribute routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a route mapping for each of these two cases. Just add a second route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"RouteFlights2",
"{action}/{path}/{date}",
new { controller = "Flight", 
action = "flights",
path = UrlParameter.Optional, 
date = UrlParameter.Optional }
,new[] { "parvaz24pro.Controllers" }
);
```